# JSONP AJAX returning correct values but with errors

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jsonp

I have an asp page that is pulling the data for whoever is logged in on a windows machine like so:

```
<%
Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
username=(Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER"))
username=replace(username,"CORP\","")
%>
<%=username%>
```

On a different domain I call this page with a ajax jsonp call like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://myDomain/get_cur_user.asp',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }   
});
```

What I get back is this:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://myDomain/get_cur_user.asp?callback=jQuery1102012502304464578629_1394753532582&_=1394753532583". jquery-1.10.2.js:8516
Uncaught ReferenceError: theOutputedUserName is not defined get_cur_user.asp?callback=jQuery1102012502304464578629_1394753532582&_=1394753532583:1
parsererrorError: jQuery1102012502304464578629_1394753532582 was not called
```

The "OutPutedUserName" is exactly what I want back. So it is "working" but is blowing up at the same time. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer to my own question.

My classic ASP page looks like this:

```
<%
   dim callback
   username = replace((Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")),"CORP\","")
   callback = Request("callback")
   Response.Write(callback & "([{""id"": """& username &"""}])")
%>
```

And my Javascript(JQuery) looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://myDomain/get_cur_user.asp',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(textStatus + errorThrown);
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }   
});
```

Many thanks to this site I came across:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/classic-asp-and-jsonp-output